# Quantum Computing Qiskit - How to read data from classical registers

Tags: programming, qiskit

```
from qiskit import *

qr   = QuantumRegister(3)
cr   = ClassicalRegister(3)
circ = QuantumCircuit(qr,cr)

circ.h(qr[0])
circ.h(qr[1])
circ.h(qr[2])

circ.measure(qr,cr)
```

now **cr[0]** maybe **0** or **1**

I want to know or copy its value to another normal variable to use it in my calculation, something like 
`if(cr[0]==0) cr_val=0 else cr_val=1`

Comment: is `cr_val` a variable that will be used outside of qiskit, or will it be used to affect your circuit in some way?

Comment: `cr_val` will be used to read the value of all **cr**  `cr[0],cr[1],cr[2]` to calculate the **decimal** value of cr to print as decimal not as binary

Comment: i want to copy the cr_val before the execute command, to store this value and reset the circuit and calculate again

Answer (score 3):

Answering based off of the extra clarity from your comments:

#### Wanting to calculate the decimal value of all `cr` as opposed to the binary

This can be done by using the Python built in function `int()`. This function will return the integer value of the input in base 10 (decimal). So you can retrieve the `counts` from the job by calling `job.result().get_counts(<circuit_name>)`. This will return a dictionary with the keys being the output from the `ClassicalRegister`s and the values being the number of times that output was measured. If you take the keys from `counts` and input them into `int()` then it will return each output as a decimal value.

#### Wanting to store values from `cr` before the execute command

To my knowledge, there is no way to read the values from `cr` before executing the circuit. The values are only populated into the ClassicalRegisters after measuring the circuit, which can only be done during the execution of the circuit.

You say you want to store the values from `cr` and reset the circuit and calculate again. This is possible, as you can just read the outputs you get from `counts`, then do something to the circuit based on those results, and then run the circuit again.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to excute the whole quantum algorithm again and again bases on the previous result then use while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I find two answers: (code tested and working)

- Answer (1) (read the register value before the execute command)

```
from qiskit import *
qiskit.IBMQ.disable_accounts()
IBMQ.enable_account('change to your api','change to your url')
#backend = qiskit.IBMQ.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
backend = qiskit.IBMQ.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')

qr  = QuantumRegister  (4)# 1110
qq  = QuantumRegister  (4)# will set to 1110 dependin on cr read
cr  = ClassicalRegister(4)
cc  = QuantumCircuit(qr,qq,cr)

cc.x(qr[1]);cc.x(qr[2]);cc.x(qr[3])# 1110

#---the important code start:----------------------------------------
for i in range(4):
    cc.measure(qr[i],cr[0])#read qr to set qq depending on the read of the classical register value using (if) condition
    cc.reset(qq[i]) # qq[i] = 0
    cc.x(qq[i]).c_if(cr,1) # if(cr == 1): qq[i] = 1 , test the whole cr decimal value, it can hold {0 to (2^n)-1}
#---the important code end--------------------------------------------

for i in range(4): cc.measure(qq[i],cr[i])#read qq

job=qiskit.execute(cc,backend,shots=1024)
result=job.result()
counts=result.get_counts(cc)
print(counts) # {'1110': 1024}
```

--- execute result ---

```
{'1110': 1024}
```

.

.

- Answer (2) (read the register value after the execute command)

```
from qiskit import *
qiskit.IBMQ.disable_accounts()
IBMQ.enable_account('change to your api','change to your url')
#backend = qiskit.IBMQ.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
backend = qiskit.IBMQ.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')

qr  = QuantumRegister  (4)# 1110
cr  = ClassicalRegister(4)
cc  = QuantumCircuit(qr,cr)

cc.x(qr[1]);cc.x(qr[2]);cc.x(qr[3])# 1110

for i in range(4): cc.measure(qr[i],cr[i])#read

job=qiskit.execute(cc,backend,shots=1024)
result=job.result()
counts=result.get_counts(cc)
print(counts) # {'1110': 1024}

#---the important code start:----------------------------------------
lAnswer = [(k[::-1],v) for k,v in counts.items()]
lAnswer.sort(key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
Y = []
for k, v in lAnswer: Y.append( [ int(c) for c in k ] )
#---the important code end--------------------------------------------

print(Y) # [[0, 1, 1, 1]]

print(Y[0][0]) # 0
print(Y[0][1]) # 1
print(Y[0][2]) # 1
print(Y[0][3]) # 1
```

--- execute result ---

```
{'1110': 1024}
[[0, 1, 1, 1]]
0
1
1
1
```